# Missing date values in date.sum()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

this is my first question, so bear with me if i am doing something wrong :)
I am working with a data set for 2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021.
(The data set is complete with a file for each day, i have checked the files manually)
I am trying to sum some values with pandas by Groupby and datetime.
The end goal is to have a sum value for each day for the whole data set.
For some reason, the year 2020 is skipping the 4th in every month, and i cant figure out why.
i have seartch the stackoverflow, datacamp and others for many hours now without a solution.
Now i have to try ask you guys.

My code starts by making a list with all the filenames i my folder.
After that i replace "." with ":" so i can convert the dates to datetime64[ns]
(there are different date formats in the files)
the code append the dates to a list and set them in the column.
returns the files by concat in a single dataframe.
after this i am making a new column where i look for some words in another column. this new column is used for sorting the dataframe. i use .loc for this.
then i groupby.dt.date and .sum
then if a date has a value of zero i need it to show so i use .asfreq("D")
and .fillna(0)

its all good, but every 4th (4/1/2020, 4/2/2020, 4/3/2020, 4/4/2020, 4/5/2020 and so on) is missing.
But WHYYY! :)
(The file are there. if i take all the files for them self, its all good. The values are there.)

```
def FileList(): #Creates a list with all the files
    CSVFileList = []
    FilePath = 'Data/'
    FileDirectoryList = os.listdir(FilePath)
    for i in FileDirectoryList:
        if(i[-3:] == "CSV"):
            CSVFileList.append(i)
    return CSVFileList
```

```
def Concat(filelist): #Concat all the files in the list from FileList
    columns_names = ["Order_ID", "Dato", "Varenummer", "Varenavn", "Quantity", "Pris", "Pris_Sum", "Tilbehør", "col1", "col2"]
    dflist = []
    for i in filelist:
        df = pd.read_csv("Data/"+i, delimiter = ";", names = columns_names)
        DatoList = []
        for i in df["Dato"]:
            u = i.replace(".",":")
            DatoList.append(u)
        df["Dato"] = DatoList
        df['Dato'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dato']) #Convert date's to Datetime64[ns]
        dflist.append(df)
    dataframe = pd.concat(dflist)
    return dataframe
```

```
def BestillingDF(filename):    
    
    df = filename
    #New Vare_Beskrivelse
    Vare_navn = []
    Varenavn = df["Varenavn"]
    for i in Varenavn:
        i = str(i)
        i = i.lower()
        if "spareribs" in i:
            Vare_navn.append("Spareribs")
        elif "salat" in i:
            Vare_navn.append("Salat")
        elif "pommes" in i:
            Vare_navn.append("Pommes Frites")
        else:
            Vare_navn.append("")
            
    df["Vare_Navn"] = Vare_navn
    Spareribs_Vægt_List = []
    spareribsvægt = bi.Spareribs_Vægt() #Gets a value from a dict in another file
    for i in df["Varenavn"]:
        if i not in spareribsvægt:
            Spareribs_Vægt_List.append(0)
        else:
            Spareribs_Vægt_List.append(spareribsvægt[i])
    df["Spareribs_Vægt_Kuvert"] = Spareribs_Vægt_List
    df["Spareribs_Vægt_[Q*K]"] = df["Quantity"] * df["Spareribs_Vægt_Kuvert"]
    return df
```

```
def Spareribs_A_Day(filename):
    data = BestillingDF(filename)
    spare = data.loc[data["Vare_Navn"] == "Spareribs"] #Sorts the dataframe 

    s = spare.groupby([spare['Dato'].dt.date])['Spareribs_Vægt_Kuvert'].sum() #Groups the series by date/day and sums the value

    t = s.asfreq('D') #Shows the zero values (NaN)

    df = pd.DataFrame(t)
    df['Spareribs_Vægt_Kuvert'] = df['Spareribs_Vægt_Kuvert'].fillna(0) #Fills the NAN by zero
    return df
```

```
def main():
        
    filelist = FileList()
    concat_DF = Concat(filelist)
    ribs = Spareribs_A_Day(concat_DF)
    print(ribs.head())

main()
```

I am no champion in python or coding. but i hope that you guys maybe can help me anyhow :)
[the code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs14u.png)

Comment: Include sample data as text and expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: We'd need to see examples of the values of the date column which are not appearing in the output, Otherwise we are just guessing as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick respons from David Erickson & John D.
i will remember to post Data Sample next time i post a question.
(the problem with this data sample is that it is very big. And the problem will not show up when the data sample is "perfect")

but, but, but, I found the answer... in a way.... :)

my .csv files have a Date inside the file. the one i was using. the date format changed over time, and i tried to tackle that.
i changed the dates to the same format, and it looked like it was all good.
but evry time the .day turned shifted to the same number as .month (4/4/2020 or 7/7/2020, 9/9/2020, and so on) the format changed (%Y-%m-%d & %Y-%d-%m)
then when i used

```
spare.groupby([spare['CleanD'].dt.date])['SpareVægtSum'].sum()
```

The sum was all wired.
its not the hole problem, but it was a pattern i found.
my solution was to get the Date from the filename and the -1 day like:

```
def CleanD():
    file = FileList()
    df_list = []
    for i in file:
        columns_names = ["Order_ID", "Dato", "Varenummer", "Varenavn", "Quantity", "Pris", "Pris_Sum", "Tilbehør", "col1", "col2"]
        df = pd.read_csv("Data/"+i, delimiter = ";", names = columns_names)
        cleanD_list = []
        for u in df["Dato"]:
            cleanD_list.append(i[0:10])
        df["CleanD"] = cleanD_list
        df_list.append(df)
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
    
    df['CleanD']= pd.to_datetime(df['CleanD'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    
    cleanD_list = []
    for i in df["CleanD"]:
        u = i + pd.Timedelta(days=-1)
        cleanD_list.append(u)
    df['CleanD'] =  cleanD_list
    return df
```

And now its all good :)
don't know why .datetime is acting like that, maybe someone knows what/why?
but its fixed, and i have used so mutch time on it, that im happy with the solution i have found this time :=)